# "The variables input contains a field name 'userID' that is not defined for input object type 'CreateOrderInput'

Tags: javascript, react-native, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-amplify

I've been stuck with this problem in my graphQL API, and I don't know how to unsolved it.

schema.graphQL:

```
type User @model {
  id: ID!
  username: String!
  email: String!

  orders: [Order] @connection(keyName: "byUser", fields: ["id"])
}

type Car @model {
  id: ID!
  type: String!
  latitude: Float,
  longitude: Float,
  heading: Float,
  isActive: Boolean

  orders: [Order] @connection(keyName: "byCar", fields: ["id"])
}

type Order @model
  @key(name: "byUser", fields: ["userId"])
  @key(name: "byCar", fields: ["carId", "createAt"]) {
  id:ID!
  createAt: ID!

  type: String!

  originLatitude: Float!
  originLongitude: Float!

  destLatitude: Float!
  destLongitude: Float!

  userId: ID! // I think theres something wrong at here.
  user: User @connection(fields: ["userId"])

  carId: ID!
  car: Car @connection(fields: ["carId"])
}
```

Mutations.js (Generated by AWS):

```
export const createOrder = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation CreateOrder(
    $input: CreateOrderInput!
    $condition: ModelOrderConditionInput
  ) {
    createOrder(input: $input, condition: $condition) {
      id
      createAt
      type
      originLatitude
      originLongitude
      destLatitude
      destLongitude
      userId
      user {
        id
        username
        email
        orders {
          nextToken
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      carId
      car {
        id
        type
        latitude
        longitude
        heading
        isActive
        orders {
          nextToken
        }
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
  }
`;
```

code:

```
    // submit to server
        try {
            const userInfo = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();

            const date = new Date();
            const input = {
                createAt: date.toISOString(),
                type,
                originLatitude: originPlace.details.geometry.location.lat || 0,
                originLongitude: originPlace.details.geometry.location.lng || 0,

                destLatitude: destinationPlace.details.geometry.location.lat || 0,
                destLongitude: destinationPlace.details.geometry.location.lng || 0,
                
                userID: userInfo.attributes.sub,
                carID: "1",
            }

            const response = await API.graphql (
                graphqlOperation (
                    createOrder, {
                        input: input
                    },
                )
            )

            console.log(response);
            Alert.alert (
                "Order has been submitted successful!!!",
                [{
                    text: "Go home",
                    onPress: () => navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')
                }]
            )
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }
```

when I try to submit it to the server it gave me an error.

> {"data": null, "errors": [{"locations": null, "message": "The
> variables input contains a field name 'userID' that is not defined for
> input object type 'CreateOrderInput' ", "path": null}]}

Comment: "userID" is not the same as "userId"

Comment: ahhhh I found out!!! in my code supposed to be userId instead of userID. my bad. THANK YOU